# Scroll panel with image using keyboard (PageDown / PageUp)

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, panel

What is right way to show large image in Winforms app with scroll-bars and keyboard scroll support?
Currenty i'm use Panel(AutoScroll=True) with nested PitureBox (SizeMod = AutoSize).

I have 2 question:

1) What control select for drawing image?
Panel and PitureBox cant be selected (focused) using Tab key. Using Button with AutoSize = true and FlatStyle = Flat is right solution?

2)How to scroll image in panel using keyboard. What keyboard events a need handle - Form, Panel or PictureBox. May be I should set for Panel AutoScroll=false and add to them HScroll and VScroll, that events I should handle?

What is right way for implement this elementary app?

(Just for info, main form have other Panel(Dock=Top) that contain some controls.)

Comment: Pleae see my updated answer!

Answer (score 1):

- As for the first question: There is no Control which is really well suited to draw on and still can get the `Focus`. In the link below you can see how to make a *selectable panel*, though.
- Now for the real problem: How to scroll an `AutoScroll Panel` by keyboard..?

This is amazingly hard to do. Here is an example for a start:

```
private void Form1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
  if (panel1.Bounds.Contains( this.PointToClient( Cursor.Position )  ))
  {
    if (e.KeyValue == 33) panel1.AutoScrollPosition = 
      new Point(panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X, Math.Abs(panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y) - 10);

    if (e.KeyValue == 34) panel1.AutoScrollPosition = 
      new Point(panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X, Math.Abs(panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y) + 10);
  }
}
```

I test for the `Panel` to contain the mouse. You may want to play around with the scroll amount.. Also replace the `KeyValues` with proper `Keys` ;-)  Set `KeyPreview = true;` for the Form!

**Note: This only works if there is no Control on the Form which can get the Focus.**

Since most likely you have some such `Controls`, like `Buttons`, `ListBoxes` etc.. here is another solution, which works in any case, I believe..:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (panel1.Bounds.Contains(this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)))
    switch (keyData)
    {
        case Keys.PageDown: { scroll(10);  return true; }
        case Keys.PageUp:   { scroll(-10); return true; }
       // maybe code for some more keys..?
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}

void scroll(int delta)
{
    panel1.AutoScrollPosition =  new Point(
           panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X, Math.Abs(panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y) + delta);
}
```

This doesn't need the Form to have `KeyPreview = true;`.

[Here is the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscrollposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explanation for `AutoScrollPosition`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702846/c-windows-forms-getting-keystrokes-in-a-panel-picturebox) is a post that suggests using a subclass for `Panel` and/or `PictureBox`, which is supposed to allow them to get `Focus`. I couldn't get that to work though..(Nor does it seem to be any simpler in the end..)