# How to stop VScrollbar from flashing when selected

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar

I have a System.Windows.Forms.VScrollBar control on my form and select it programmatically by calling `scrollBar.Select()` so that mouse-wheel and keyboard scrolling *just works* (without the user having to explicitly select the scrollbar beforehand). However, this causes the scrollbar cursor to constantly flash every half a second or so. Is there any way to stop this behaviour? I have looked around but I can't find any property to control this behaviour?

I even tried creating a custom scrollbar inherting from VScrollBar and overriding OnPaint, but that's not even getting called, so I guess its not used by VScrollBar at all.

Comment: Can you show the scroll code and from where are you calling *scrollBar.Select()*?

Comment: It's actually code straight from Microsoft and it's used in their System.ComponentModel.Design.ByteViewer class. There's some example code on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.byteviewer(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_8) that you can run and it demonstrates the problem nicely. I have since looked at the implementation of VScrollBar and it's a simple wrapper for the ancient WINAPI scrollbar so I don't think there's a simple way to change that behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that keyboard scrolling can be easily implemented on a WinForms `AutoScroll` control (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27331826/8061994)). I do know that so long as the `AutoScroll` control has focus in the form, mouse-wheel scrolling should work without the user selecting the scrollbar itself. I suggest that rather than calling `scrollBar.Select()` to accomplish what you need, you instead call `scrollBarParent.Focus()`. This should take care of the flashing issue.

Comment: Why is it so difficult to scroll with keyboard? You intersept the *key-up or down* and send the *WM_SCROLL* message to parent if it is autoscroll or to the vertical scroll bar itself with the *LOWORD WPARAM* *SB_LINEDOWN or SB_LINEUP*. [WM_VSCROLL message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/wm-vscroll)

Comment: I’ve never tried it myself. I am referencing information I’ve seen in other answers. If you have done it successfully before, perhaps you could provide an answer with details.

Comment: Thanks, I have now done something similar. Instead of calling Select() on the Scrollbar control, I have overridden OnMouseWheel and OnKeyDown in the parent and forward the events to the scrollbar control.